# Checkout the git commit corresponding to a certain revision from the old SVN repository?

Tags: git, svn, git-checkout, revision, svn-checkout

I migrated my repository from SVN to git. I used 
[THIS](http://www.jonmaddox.com/2008/03/05/cleanly-migrate-your-subversion-repository-to-a-git-repository/) site. Now I have a bug in revision X. How do I checkout from my git repository, knowing only the revision number from my old SVN repo?

Thank you for your Help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find the git commit that corresponds to the Subversion revision with the `git svn find-rev` subcommand.  For example, if you're looking for the commit that corresponds to Subversion revision 3431 you can do:

```
$ git svn find-rev r3431
42ed8bcf690fd0c655c5cee91b09258318fc56e8
```

Then, to checkout that revision, just use the object name from the first line, e.g. if it's:

```
commit 42ed8bcf690fd0c655c5cee91b09258318fc56e8
Author: torstenrohlfing <torstenrohlfing@42a5c34f-2066-0410-bec5-ba365beb4995>
Date:   Fri Sep 9 17:11:38 2011 +0000

    FIX: do not update time stamps on pre-existing files that did not get updated.


    git-svn-id: https://www.nitrc.org/svn/cmtk/trunk@3431 42a5c34f-2066-0410-bec5-ba365beb4995
```

You can do:

```
git checkout 42ed8bcf69
```

... to try that revision.  (Note that this will detach HEAD, so if you don't know what that means, it would be worth searching for "detached HEAD" first :))

Comment: Hi, that does not work. I don't have this trunk-id in my commit log.

Comment: Do you have multiple git branches?  Have you run `git svn rebase` recently?  Can you find the most recent commit on your branch that has a `git-svn-id` line in the log at all?  (e.g. with `git log --grep=git-svn-id`)

Comment: git svn rebase: there is no upstream svn information in my working tree history. So didn't it fetch the whole repos?

Comment: Great, I'm glad to hear you got that sorted out :)

Comment: A oneliner for this can be: `git svn fetch && git checkout $(git svn find-rev r3431)`. Note that this revision needs to exist.