# Checkout a specific svn release in the local git repository

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I would like to checkout a specific check-in just by knowing the `svn` release number. For example, when I clone a subversion repository to a local git using `git-svn clone`, I get the following message:

```
r5119 = 1563c2dcb9f456d5ba1ba2c277bf7969c452d18b (refs/remotes/git-svn)
    M   check-svn.c
    M   Makefile
r5127 = 1b656753fe46287f52f29359793b2d8671137f4b (refs/remotes/git-svn)
    M   check-svn.c
r5129 = edd06d73d270769cc46db58d9a1a0a4683c95be1 (refs/remotes/git-svn)
    M   check-svn.c
r5132 = 39bf8333113f1ccc6b839cf944dd88c560509065 (refs/remotes/git-svn)
Checked out HEAD:
  https://svn.myserver.net/check-svn r5132
```

So, we can see that the `svn` release tags are known (`r5119`, `r5127`, ...).

What I would like to do is to get back to an old release of the `svn` repository on my local `git` clone just by knowing the `svn` release number. For example, to do something like:

```
git checkout r5129
```

And get the code of the `svn` release `r5129` in my local `git` clone.

My problem is that I don't see how to do this even if I see that the tags are well positioned. For example, when I do a `git shortlog` as follow:

```
  git-svn-id: https://svn.myserver.net/check-svn@5119 bb18-a6e4ad0ded21
  git-svn-id: https://svn.myserver.net/check-svn@5127 bb18-a6e4ad0ded21
  git-svn-id: https://svn.myserver.net/check-svn@5129 bb18-a6e4ad0ded21
  git-svn-id: https://svn.myserver.net/check-svn@5132 bb18-a6e4ad0ded21
```

So, how to do such feature easily (if possible without extra manipulation at the initial cloning) ?

Comment: Is this answer helpful to you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599707/checkout-the-git-commit-corresponding-to-a-certain-revision-from-the-old-svn-rep

Comment: This is definitely helpful, even if I would have preferred a simpler solution (I don't blame you for that! It's just a naive wish).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't like the solution with `git svn find-rev`, you could try:

```
git checkout ':/@5127 '
```

If git is given an string starting with `:/` as a revision, it will use the most recent commit where the log message matches the following regular expression.  Since git-svn will typically include the revision information in the log message this search can work for that as well.  Note the space before the closing quote, that will prevent matching a revision like 51271 if you have that many revisions in the svn history; if you know that the revision you're looking for is recent enough to not have that problem you could leave out the quotes altogether.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would like to thank [Matthijs P](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34103/matthijs-p) who lead me to the solution with his comment.

`git-svn` has a sub-command `find-rev` that allow to link a `git` hash-tag and an `svn` revision label (see the `git-svn` [manpage](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html) for more). So, basically, checking out a specific revision from the remote `svn` is done like this:

```
git checkout `git svn find-rev r5127`
```

Beware, because you won't be on a branch, so if you perform modifications, it will be difficult to merge (except if you rebase it first).

In my case, this is just a read-only access, so this is fine for me.